# Create fixtures from a list of countries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a country table with a list countries in it. And I want to get the output as possible fixtures like in a world cup.

```
Sample country table input -
-----
col
-----
eng
sa
aus

Output -
------------
col1   col2
------------
aus    eng
eng    sa
sa     aus
```

I came up with the below solution with self join, but this creates duplicates in the fixtures like aus v eng and eng v aus.

```
select a.col as col1, b.col as col2
    from country a
    join country b
    on a.col != b.col
```

Another approach I tried was using LEAD function. This works, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
select 
  col1, 
  case when col2 is not null then col2
       else (select top 1 col from country order by col)
  end as col2
from
    (select 
      col as col1, 
      lead(col,1) over (order by col) as col2 
    from country) t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first version is very close.  You want `<` rather than not equal:

```
select a.col as col1, b.col as col2
from country a join
     country b
     on a.col < b.col
```

Answer (score 1):

Option using the window function `lead() over()` and `first_value() over()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([col] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('eng')
,('sa')
,('aus')


Select Col
      ,Col2 = coalesce(lead(Col,1) over (order by col),first_value(col) over (order by col))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
Col Col2
aus eng
eng sa
sa  aus
```